# Add column to model, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add to my model Treatment an column, so that it belongs_to a category:

```
  class CreateTreatments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  create_table :treatments do |t|
  t.string :typ
  t.string :content
  t.date :day
  t.references :patient


  t.timestamps
 end
  add_index :treatments, :patient_id
  add_index :treatments, :category_id
 end
 end
```

i want to add:

```
  t.references :category
```

and

```
  add_index :treatments, :category_id
```

I tried it simply copying it in and running a migration but it didnt`t worked! I know normally i would simply make an

```
 rails g model Treatment category:references
```

How can i achieve this afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate another migration:

```
rails g migration add_category_id_to_treatments category_id:integer
```

You ought to edit automatically generated migration and add line on the end of `change` method:

```
add_index :treatments, :category_id
```

Then you should run migration.